# How to make a bat file which find a file path and copy a specific file to an other location

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to make a bat file that first will search the path for the executable "Text.exe".
Then i want to copy a log.log file from the path that i founded , in thr folder LOg and copy this file to a server \server1\logFiles

Can you help me with an exemple?

Answer (score 0):

Where `c:\searchlocation` is the path within which you want to search:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir /b /s C:\searchlocation\Text.exe') do (
    copy "%%~pFLog.log" "\server1\logFiles"
)
```